# Cannot instantiate the type Select in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to simulate a test case where i have to select multiple option from a multipleselect box. i can do this using select. however i am getting following error as soon as i instantiate select.

"Cannot instantiate the type Select"

my code is:

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.apache.bcel.generic.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class SeleniumFormTesting {
//piece of code to open the browser in firefox

Select selectBox = new Select(driver.findElement(By
            .cssSelector("select#id_contact")));
//in above select statement the error comes

}
```

can someone please help me in getting rid of this problem

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using the `Select` import package. You can import it into your project using:

`import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, now the error is gone. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Thank you! I was also having same strange issue.

Comment: Don't forget to add `selenium-support` dependency: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-support

Answer (score 1):

Try by importing the `Select` support package:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.List;
import org.apache.bcel.generic.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class SelectDOB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Code to open browser and facebook page
        Select s  = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='day']")));
        s.selectByVisibleText("10");
        Select s  = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='month']")));
        s.selectByVisibleText("May");
        Select s  = new Select(driver.fintdElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='year']")));
        s.selectByVisibleText("1980");
    }}
tried with this, still am getting error
Am getting "Cannot instantiate the type Select",
```

Comment: Add some description to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Remove >> import org.apache.bcel.generic.Select;

Use only >>  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

for me it worked.

Comment: Please add an explanation as to why this worked for you and why you think this might work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I followed this instruction, and it works for me
Remove >> import org.apache.bcel.generic.Select;

Use only >> import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).